# Webpack somehow bypasses Express routing completely

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I am starting from this excellent tutorial: https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/ and trying to extend it by adding a new page to serve through a new route. However after hours of mucking around I am realizing that somehow create-react-app is doing some weird magic (as [mentioned in their docs here](https://github.com/fullstackreact/food-lookup-demo)):

```
`create-react-app` configures a Webpack development server to run on `localhost:3000`. 

This development server will bundle all static assets located under `client/src/`. 

All requests to `localhost:3000` will serve `client/index.html` which will include Webpack's `bundle.js`.
```

The key quote is "All requests to `localhost:3000` will serve `client/index.html`". I have no idea how this happens. So even though i mess around with `routes/index.js`:

```
   app.route('/')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            res.sendFile(bipath.join(__dirname, '../public', 'THISCANBEANYRANDOMFILENAME.html'))
        });
```

it doesnt matter because webpack is somehow directing `localhost:3000` to index.html anyway. where and how is it doing this? Bottom line I am trying to modify my routes to serve a new html file and am running into all sorts of filepath issues (yes, even when i use `require('path')` or `sendFile(...,{root: __dirname})`.)

So what exactly is going on here and can you give me any hints to help me out?

Edit: this could be from babel as well as webpack - i'm not exactly clear where babel hands off and where webpack starts.

[image: this is my problem in one picture]

Comment: here is the files on github if you need more information: https://github.com/sw-yx/fcc-nightlife

Comment: All Babel does is transpile. I don't understand why you think hitting the root endpoint doesn't hit the path--that's the `index.html` we're talking about, isn't it?

Comment: yes. i can prove to myself that hitting the root endpoint doesnt hit the path because i intentionally edited the sendFile to send a nonexistent file - "indextest.html" in the screenshot above, and when i hit it in my browser it STILL SERVED INDEX.HTML. So it clearly was getting intercepted somewhere by webpack dev server. What is black magic is I don't even see any webpack dev server configs anywhere (i have posted the github) so I have no idea how it is doing any of this interception.

Comment: Are you re-compiling? (Well, re-transpiling and bundling, via watching, or...?)

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, recompiling every time. Its a real thing. Evidence provided by that create-react-app quote about intercepting, as well as Jon's comments below that this intercepting thing exists. i have no idea how this black magic is happening!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played around with create-react-app, but it seems like instead of using the default npm start, you could create your own server file and run that.

This looks like a good example.

https://medium.com/@patriciolpezjuri/using-create-react-app-with-react-router-express-js-8fa658bf892d#.6y4rrl61q

Alternatively, if you're looking to have routes used as an api, you could proxy them to a different port like shown in the tutorial you linked.

Comment: yes the APIs are working perfectly. the tutorial shows you how to dualboot an API server and a client server. so its the client server i'm having a problem with: the html serving is basically black magic because it somehow doesnt respect routes/index.js and I have no idea why!

Comment: when you run npm start the default create-react-app run script will start a webpack dev server that intercepts all requests. you can possibly get around this by not running the default run script and instead writing your own server.js that will handle starting the non-api server. not sure if there's a cleaner solution built into create-react-app

Comment: thanks for your answers so far @Jon. I think I may need to write my own run script. What I dont understand is I don't even seem to have any webpack modules in my node_modules folder. Nor can I find the `webpack.config.js` file that would be needed to intercept these requests. in my package.json (https://github.com/sw-yx/fcc-nightlife/blob/master/package.json) the tutorial uses `babel-node` to launch the server and the client and again I have no idea where `babel-node` even comes from. so many mysteries.

Comment: looks like the scripts that they run by default are in the node_modules/react-scripts folder. you can take a look in there to see what happens when you run npm start